# Appending a circle to all the rects within a group using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, hover, append

I am attempting to append a circle to all the nested rectangles that are within the a group which has the same class of the rect I'm hovering/clicking on.  I have added a mouseover event to the rect and used a d3 selection

```
.on("mouseover", function (d, i){

    var ypos = d3.selectAll("g." + this.id).selectAll("rect").attr('y');
    var xpos = d3.selectAll("g." + this.id).selectAll("rect").attr('x');

    d3.selectAll("g." + this.id).append("circle")
                            .attr("cx", xpos)
                            .attr("cy", ypos)
                            .attr("r", 30)
                            .style("fill" , "red")
                            .style("opacity", 0.1);

                          d3.selectAll("g." + this.id).select("*").style("fill", "red");

                      })
```

Although the circles are being appended to every group that has that class, they are being appended with the x,y coordinated of the first rect that meets the selection criteria and i'm struggling to find a way to grab the coordinates of each rectangle and apply the circles to each of those sets of coordinates.

Comment: Could you create a complete testcase that runs e.g. a jsfiddle or a stack snippet.

Comment: This is because you're appending ALL of the circles at `xpos,ypos`. Change the `cx` and `cy` attributes to be relative to each rectangle, e.g.: `.attr("cx", function (){return d3.select(this).attr("x");});`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.. However instead the circles are being appended to the top left hand corner and when i inspect the circle tags they've been added without x and y coordinates. :/  I guess at that point "this" has become the circle when its the coordinates of the rectangle I need?